# How many times may a loop be executed in a multithreaded C++ program?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

This is an interview question.

```
class X 
{
    int i = 0 ;

public: 
    Class *foo()
    {
        for (  ;  i < 1000 ; ++i )
        {
            // some code but do not change value of i 
        }
    }
}    

int main()
{
    X myX ; 
    Thread  t1 = create_thread( myX.foo() ) ;
    Thread  t2 = create_thread( myX.foo() ) ; 
    Start t1 ...
    Start t2 ...
    join(t1)
    joint(t2)
}
```

Q1: if the code run on 1-cpu processor, how many times can the for-loop run in worst case?

Q2: what if the code run on 2-cpu processor, how many times can the for-loop run in worst case?

My ideas:

The loop may run infinite times, because a thread can run it many times before the other thread updates the value of `i`.

Or, when t1 is suspended, t2 runs 1000 times and then we have 1000 x 1000 times ?

Is this correct?

Comment: That doesn't look like C++ to me.

Comment: Did you even try to compile this? This code can not run, because it is not valid.

Comment: Are you reproducing it from memory or was the example they gave you really this bad? If I saw this I'd walk out of the interview.

Comment: I find this an odd interview question. What's going on *inside* the loop?  Stuff that has to be done over an entire collection? Or is this a linear search?? If the latter, it's `O(2n)` in the worst case, as you have two threads, each doing a max of 1000 iterations.

Comment: The `main()`  will just exit and the loops will run but the number of times loops run will be *indeterminate* at best. There has to be a **join** in `main()` for main thread to wait till child threads complete their task.

Comment: Since `X::foo()` does not return anything, despite its signature promising that it will, you get at best undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Als: The join may be done in the destructor of the Thread class, who knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`create_thread( myX.foo() )` calls `create_thread` with the return value of `myX.foo()`. `myX.foo()` is run on the main thread, so `myX.i` will eventually have a value of 1000 (which is the value which it has after two calls to `myX.foo()`).

If the code was actually meant to run `myX.foo()` twice on a two different threads concurrently, then the code would have undefined behaviour (due to the race condition in the access to `myX.i`). So yes, the loop could run an infinite number of times (or zero times, or the program could decide to get up and eat a bagel).

Comment: So if it runs on a 1 cpu processor, how many times will the for loop iterate?  (is i shared on each thread, meaning 1000, or copied meaning 2000)

Comment: In what scenario it will run infinite times?

Comment: @Tom: There is not really enough information in the question to say whether `i` is shared between the threads or not, but assuming it is, then behaviour is undefined. Whether it is running on a 1 CPU processor or a 100 CPU processor does not come into this. The answer is not `1000` or `2000`, it is undefined. It could be either of these things, or it could be neither, or it could even be both. Undefined means that you don't know.

Comment: But with 1 cpu there cannot be simultaneous access to i?  The two threads cannot simulteanously read and write to i, garbling the value.  There will be 1000 iterations, no?

Comment: Okay, yes, got it (sorry).  The increment of i is not atomic, so the the threads can still garbel the value of i, even if there is one cpu - each thread can still be halfway though the instruction when the other thread accesses i.

Comment: @Tom No: the compiler is free to load `i` once into a register, keep it there for the entire loop execution, and write it back to `i` at the end of the loop. On a single-CPU machine, this could result in 1000, or 2000 iterations, depending on how the threads are interleaved. If the compiler decided to spill the register back to `i` in some parts of the loop, but not in other parts, then you can get other values for number of iterations. And if the compiler can "see into" the body of the loop, and decide that it has no side-effects, then you can get `0` iterations.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Cool, thanks, I learn something.  I think it was an interesting interview question.

Comment: @Tom: Also: it's possible that Thread1 could read `i` as 0, Thread2 could run 999 times, then Thread1 could "update" `i` to 1, etc.  Thus, even on a single core, it can run up to (roughly) 499500 times. (Assuming it wasn't undefined behavior)  On a multicore, infinite loops, as asynchronous writes to the same variable can merge, resulting in a value that neither thread wrote.  One saves "128", Other stores "127", result is "255".  (Details are complicated, but that's the gist)

Answer (score 2):

It is no matter on which type of system this code will run. Switching between threads goes in the same way.
Worst case for all cases is:
1000 + 1000 * 999 * 998 * 997 * ... * 2 * 1 times. (incorrect!!! correct one is in update)

When first thread tries to increase a variable (it already read a value, but not written yet), second thread can make all the loop from the start value of i, but when second thread finishing it's last loop, first thread increases a value of i, and second thread starts it's long job again :)

*** Updated (A little more details)

Sorry, real formula is:

1000 + 1000 + 999 + 998 + ... + 2 + 1 times,
or 500999

Each iteration of the loop looks like this:

1. Check condition.
2. Make a work.
3. Read value from i
4. Increase read value
5. Write value to i

Nobody said that step 2 has constant time. So I suppose that it has a varying and suitable for my worst case time.

Here is this worst case:

Iteration 1:

[1st thread] Makes steps 1-4 of the first loop iteration (very long work time)

[2nd thread] Makes all the loop (1000 times), but doesn't check a condition last time

Iteration 2:

[1] Maskes step 5, so now i == 1, and makes steps 1-4 of next loop iteration

[2] Makes all the loop from current i (999 times)

Iteration 3: the same as before, but i == 2

...

Iteration 1000: the same as before , but i == 999

In the end we will have 1000 Iterations and each iteration will have 1 execution of loop code from first thread and (1000 - Iteration number) executions from second thread.

Comment: I think you should mention exactly when each thread (in the worst case) updates i.  (See @EmployedRussian's comment to Mankarse answer.)  Also, as I dont think your argument (as I understand it) leads to the formula you provide.  Maybe you can provide a few more details?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with mutiplying. Extended version above.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad interview question if the code is transcribed accurately.

```
class X 
{
    int i = 0;
```

This notation is not valid C++.  G++ says:

```
3:13: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘i’ [-fpermissive]
3:13: error: making ‘i’ static [-fpermissive]
3:13: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘i’
```

We'll ignore this, assuming that the code was written as something more like:

```
class X
{
    int i;
public:
    X() : i(0) { }
```

The original code continues:

```
public: 
    Class *foo()
    {
        for (  ;  i < 1000 ; ++i )
        {
            // some code but do not change value of i 
        }
        return 0;  // Added to remove undefined behaviour
    }
}
```

It is not clear what a `Class *` is - the type `Class` is unspecified in the example.

```
int main()
{
    X myX; 
    Thread  t1 = create_thread( myX.foo() );
```

Since `foo()` is called here and its return value is passed to `create_thread()`, the loop will be executed 1000 times here - it matters not whether it is a multi-core system.  After the loops are done, the return value is passed to `create_thread()`.

Since we don't have a specification for `create_thread()`, it is not possible to predict what it will do with the `Class *` that is returned from `myX.foo()`, any more than it is possible to tell how `myX.foo()` actually generates an appropriate `Class *` or what a `Class` object is capable of doing.  The chances are that the null pointer will cause problems - however, for the sake of the question, we'll assume that the `Class *` is valid and a new thread is created and placed on hold waiting for the '*start*' operation to let it run.

```
    Thread  t2 = create_thread( myX.foo() );
```

Here we have to make some assumptions.  We may assume that the `Class *` returned by `myX.foo()` does not give access to the member variable `i` that is in `myX`.  Therefore, even if thread `t1` is running before `t2` is created, there is no interference from `t1` in the value of `myX`, and  when the main thread executes this statement, the loop will execute 0 more times.  The result from `myX.foo()` will be used to create thread `t2`, which cannot interfere with `i` in `myX` any more either.  We'll discuss variations on these assumptions below.

```
    Start t1 ...
    Start t2 ...
```

The threads are allowed to run; they do whatever is implied by the `Class *` returned from `myX.foo()`.  But the threads can neither reference nor (therefore) modify `myX`; they have not been given access to it unless the `Class *` somehow provides that access.

```
    join(t1)
    joint(t2)
```

The threads complete...

```
}
```

So, the body of the loop executes 1000 times before `t1` is created, and is executed an additional 0 times before `t2` is created.  And it does not matter whether it is a single-core or multi-core machine.

Indeed, even if you assume that the `Class *` gives the thread access to the `i` *and* you assume that `t1` starts running immediately (possibly before `create_thread()` returns to the main thread), as long as it does not modify `i`, the behaviour is guaranteed to be '1000 and 0 times'.

Clearly, if `t1` starts running when `create_thread()` is called and modifies the `i` in `myX`, then the behaviour is indeterminate.  However, while the threads are in suspended animation until the '*start*' operations, there is no indeterminacy and '1000 and 0 times' remains the correct answer.

---

#### Alternative Scenario

If the `create_thread()` calls have been misremembered and the code was:

```
Thread  t1 = create_thread(myX.foo);
Thread  t2 = create_thread(myX.foo);
```

where a pointer to member function is being passed to `create_thread()`, then the answer is quite different.  Now the function is not executed until the threads are started, and the answer is indeterminate whether there is one CPU or are several CPUs on the machine.  It comes down to thread scheduling issues and also depends on how the code is optimized.  Almost any answer between 1000 and 2000 is plausible.

Under sufficiently weird circumstances, the answer might even be larger.  For example, suppose `t2` executed and read `i` as 0, then got suspended to let `t1` run; `t1` processes iterations 0..900, and then writes back `i`, and transfers control to `t2`, which increments its internal copy of `i` to 1 and writes this back, then gets suspended, and `t1` runs again and reads `i` and runs from 1 to 900 again, and then lets `t2` have another go...etc.  Under this implausible scenario (implausible the code for `t1` and `t2` to execute is probably the same - though it all hinges on what the `Class *` really is), there could be a lot of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Worst case 2000 times assuming `main` lives till `t1` and `t2`

it can't be infinite. because if even single thread is running, it will increment `i` value.

Comment: why is it wrong? if thread1 executes initialization block before another thread finishes increment block, it will be 2000 times.

Comment: He said that there is a join missing in main and he is right. Main will just finish, ending the program before the two worker threads will have the time to actually finish their execution

Comment: @Als - your comment is grossly incorrect as well, as it completely misses the likely actual point of the question (which is almost certainly testing multithreading/race conditions knowledge), which I'd reckon is incomplete code, and written from memory.  Yes, technically main will exit here, but that's not what they're asking.   And technically, I don't think anything guarantees that the main thread won't get preempted just after starting the threads, but before exiting, for long enough to finish.

Comment: @James: :) Glad you can mind-read what the interviewer wanted to ask, when neither the OP nor the Q he posted could tell us.The actual point is my comment was based on factual information provided in the Q and I posted it as an comment because I had the feeling that the Q is incorrect or misquoted.I wonder if you were the interviewer to mind-read it, On a serious note, I don't see the point of asking technically incorrect Q's in a Technical interview.

Comment: @Als - Me too - it makes it a lot easier to actually get hired when you answer what they're actually asking. And Who says the question was  incorrect, and not the reproduction of the question?  Anyhow: I'm fairly sure I know what they're asking because I've seen it asked elsewhere (though in Java).  Same notion.

Comment: @James: Sorry I don't really want to get hired in places where they do ask invalid,incorrect Q's.I say the Q was incorrect in the form it was posted here.I have no bearing or control over what was *actually* asked to the OP.I have to go by what facts and evidences are presented before me without making any presumptions or perceptions about *what it might be*.

Comment: I think we should not only try to answer correctly but also to correct the question, in possible and obvious ways.

Comment: @James: To Quote my answer again *The main() will just exit and the loops will run but the number of times loops run will be **indeterminate** at best....*.I don't see where it mentions answer is `0`.Please get the facts correct if you want to argue on the basis of them.

Comment: @Als - you appear to have deleted the comment on this answer that I actually responded to, where you told this person they were wrong (they gave an upper bound often regarded as "worst" case) because, IIRC, main would exit immediately (to be fair: comment is gone, so I'm paraphrasing).  I was, as evidenced by the fact that my response is here, not on the main question, responding to your comment on this answer.